# Store array in Session['B'] from array In Session['A']

Tags: php, arrays, session

Say I have table below in MySQL

```
No. Item   price   code
1   apple  12.00   001
2   pear   10.00   002
3   orange  9.00   003
4   grape  15.00   004
```

I use PHP `some_page.php` start session and run query SQL, then store as `$_SESSION['A']` that has array below:

```
1   apple  12.00   001
2   pear   10.00   002
```

*(This `$_SESSION['A']` is temporary and will be unset-ed every time new query to mySQL)*

Now, before `$_SESSION['A']` is unset, is it possible to select array from `$SESSION['A']` to store to another session on the same `some_page.php` called `$SESSION['B']`? With array:

```
2   pear   10.00   002
```

*(`$_SESSION['B']` will be for longer duration)*

My logic is tat I try not to run SQL more than once just to get the array which already available from `$_SESSION['A']`.

Comment: Whats wrong with that ? it is perfectly possible

Comment: what's your problem here?

Comment: It is not like $_SESSION['B'] = $_SESSION['A'] to get the job done,  
I only want to select(indiviually) 1 or 2 arrays from $_SESSION['A'] not all..

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question but

$_SESSION is just an associative array: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

So you can do `$_SESSION['B'] = $_SESSION['A']` which will copy the array from 'A' into 'B'. Then feel free to unset 'A'.

Edit:
If you only want part of the $_SESSION['A'] array then you can access it via index like `$_SESSION['A'][0]`. Depending on the format of the array you may have to parse through it to get the elements you want.

Comment: See my edit.  $_SESSION['A'] can be an array or array of arrays or whatever type you want so you can  access and manipulate it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save into B only part of A, you can copy the entire array and then unset the indexes that you desire.
Or you can use a foreach on A, check the condition that match only your content, and then put the content into B.
Or save the content directly to B without pass through A.
Or save into A only what you want and then copy A to B.

_SESSION is an associative array, you can manipulate it as you want.
For unset an element of an array you can use `unset($array[$index])` where `$index` can be an `INT` or a `STRING`, it depend from you.